# MVC 6 WebApi SSO Credentials (FB, Google, etc.)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Let me start by saying this question will show my ignorance. I am building a new MVC 6 webapi and this time it is different as I am not on an internal network with NTLM / Kerberos.

This WebApi will be secured/limited to people who have created an account on the site. Of course our site will have an MVC front so really the authorization/authentication will happen in the mvc controller and that will be passing a token??? to the webapi?

Now we want them to be able to "associate" their fb, google and a few others with their account. The idea being that they have a sso experience.

Already signed into Google...then I want my Authentication controller to verify they are valid and if so not challenge them.

I understand there may be some libraries out there already for this and that is not what I am looking for although I will certainly research any suggestions.

What I want to know is the concepts to Google / Pluralsight to educate myself on securing the mvc / webapi this way.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because a user is logged in via Google or Facebook, that he has access to your application. You will need your own SSO that manages all your applications and users.
So you can let the user register to your application with his google,facebook or local account and then use this account to access all your different applications, that are managed by the SSO.

A good opensource .net framework is [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer), this also has lots of good documentation and examples: [Documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/)

Comment: I just got done watching the 2014 NDC video from IdentityServer folks. That is exactly what I was looking to learn. Thank You for taking the time to help!